# Postgres: Get value of a column corresponding to max of other column in a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, timescaledb

I am trying to write a postgres query which returns max, min, median, first and last values in a group along with the timestamp column for each aggregate value

Table

```
Id Timestamp_utc                  Value
1  2020-11-05 15:36:15.768388     10
1  2020-11-05 15:40:15.768388     20
1  2020-11-05 15:44:15.768388     30
1  2020-11-05 15:45:15.768388.    5
1  2020-11-05 15:59:15.768388     25
1  2020-11-05 16:59:15.768388     25
```

Expected Result

```
Id Median Median_Timestamp Min Min_Timestamp               Max Max_TimeStamp
1  17.5.  15:44:15.768388  5   2020-11-05 15:45:15.768388  30   2020-11-05 15:44:15.768388
```

I have this query which groups data doesn't include the timestamp

```
SELECT Id, time_bucket('60', timestamp_utc) AS bucket,
percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) median_value,
min(value) min_value, 
max(value) max_value 
FROM rs.MyTable 
WHERE id IN ( 1111,123)
AND timestamp_utc Between '2020-11-05 10:00:15.748643' and '2020-11-05 16:35:48.750313'
GROUP BY id, bucket 
ORDER BY id, bucket
```

**Is there a way I could get timestamp column as well for the aggregated value like timestamp_utc col data when the value is maximum?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses window functions in a subquery to rank the timestamps by increasing and descending `value`, then conditional aggregation in the outer query to bring the relevant values

```
select id, bucket,
    percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) median_value,
    min(value) min_value, 
    max(timestamp_utc) filter(where rn_asc = 1) min_timestamp,
    max(value) max_value,
    max(timestamp_utc) filter(where rn_desc = 1) max_timestamp
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by id, bucket order by value) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by id, bucket order by value desc) rn_desc
    from (
        select t.*, time_bucket('60', timestamp_utc) as bucket 
        from rs.mytable t
        where 
            id in (1111,123)
            and timestamp_utc between '2020-11-05 10:00:15.748643'::timestamp 
                                  and '2020-11-05 16:35:48.750313'::timestamp
    ) t
) t
group by id, bucket 
order by id, bucket
```

Note that we need to compute the bucket first, and put it in the partition of the window function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the above query is always giving NULL timestamps for min and max though the table rows has timestamps  for max and min values

Comment: I think the time_bucket function is messing it up?

Comment: @DoIt: yes, that's possible. Does it work if you remove it from the query?

Comment: Yes but I only get one row per id which is not expected case for me

Comment: That is genious. Could we apply this to median as well, like if the bucket has odd number of items, get the middle value and corresponding timestamp, it its even then avg of middle two values and timestamp of first of those two middle values?

Comment: @DoIt: that's probably doable... But that's not the question you asked in the first place! You might want to ask a new question for this.